# Возможна ли такая форма повелительного наклонения?

Tags: грамматика, недопустимая-метка, глаголы, наклонение-глагола

Я читал, что глаголы в повелительном наклонении могут быть только 2 и 3 лица. В Википедии я нашёл, что глаголы повелительного наклонения могут быть 1 лица множественного числа:пойдёмте. 1 лица единственного числа у глаголов повелительного наклонения я не нашёл. Я считаю, что такая форма возможна: "пусть я буду поваром". Можно ли считать такую форму повелительным наклонением 1 лица единственного числа?

Comment: "Пусть" ("пусти") - это всё-таки форма 2-го лица, мне думается.  А формы третьего лица я и представить не могу.  По-моему они всегда второго, в силу того, что эта форма используется в прямой речи собеседнику.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Повелительное наклонение глаголов выражает волеизъявление говорящего: просьбу, приказ или побуждение к действию.

2) **Основными формами** повелительного наклонения являются формы **2 лица ед. и мн. числа**: встань – встаньте, играй - играйте, говори – говорите.

Форма повелительного наклонения ( **2-ого  лица ед. числа**) образуется от основы настоящего времени с помощью суффикса И (бери), суффикса Й (читай) или нулевого суффикса (сядь).

Для образования формы **2-ого лица мн. числа**  дополнительно используется  окончание (или постфикс) ТЕ.

**3) Другие формы:**

А) частицы ПУСТЬ, ПУСКАЙ, ДА + глагол в форме **3 л. ед. и мн. числа**: пусть поют, да здравствует мир;

б) частиц ДАВАЙ (ДАЙ), ДАВАЙТЕ (ДАВАЙ) + глагол в форме **1 л. ед. и мн. числа**: давайте я схожу;

в) идём, поедем, полетим (глаголы **1 л**. мн. числа)